# How to fail a Maven build on a missing parameter?

Tags: java, maven-2, parameters, build, environment-variables

I have a environment variable or jvm parameter which must be present. How do I get Maven to fail if this parameter does not exist?

Comment: After searching for maven-enforcer-plugin I found also this questions on SO:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425198/can-i-force-maven-2-to-require-a-property-to-be-specified-on-the-command-line

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059468/forcing-the-user-to-enter-a-property-using-maven

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use the [requireProperty goal of the maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html).